# XGBoost Installation in windows

Tags: python, machine-learning, xgboost

I am trying to install xgboost in anaconda in windows environment. Win 8.1, 64-bit, Python-3.5. How can I create a shared library for xgboost as mention in

> Installation Guide
>
> This page gives instructions on how to build and
>   install the xgboost package from scratch on various systems. It
>   consists of two steps:
>
> First build the shared library from the C++ codes (libxgboost.so for
>   linux/osx and libxgboost.dll for windows). Exception: for R-package
>   installation please directly refer to the R package section. Then
>   install the language packages (e.g. Python Package).

I searched for solution but more or less same solution is available. Can anyone help me out with installation procedure in windows.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to follow the instructions under ["Building on Windows"](http://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build.html#building-on-windows). They're mostly correct, but sometimes a bit unclear.

For instance, you need to start with the git clone command which is mentioned for other OSes above, but not for Windows. Then, follow instructions as given there. For compiling with MinGW, you'll also have to [download that](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/) (specifically, the 64 bits version), and add its folder which contains the `mingw32-make.exe` file (I guess it's a `bin` folder) to your PATH environment variable.

Comment: Do you know any other methods? It is really not hitting what to do.

Comment: I downloaded that mingw file but when i installed it the it shows me error- Repository cannot be downloaded

Comment: @ShubhamBhewanewala that installer works fine for me right now, can you try again? By the way, forgot to mention, when installing it, when the installer asks to specify some settings, you have to choose x86_64 architecture and win32 under Threads. Leave rest at default. And no, don't know any other methods, struggled a bit to install this myself recently, having to google around for solutions sometimes