# XGBoost with GPU support installation error: can't copy 'xgboost\lib': doesn't exist or not a regular file

Tags: python, installation, xgboost

Similar non-duplicate posts:

- [How to install xgboost package in python (windows platform)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33749735/how-to-install-xgboost-package-in-python-windows-platform)
- [XGBoost installation issues for Python Anaconda Windows 10 (18 May 2018)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50420693/xgboost-installation-issues-for-python-anaconda-windows-10-18-may-2018)

I looked around through multiple Stack Overflow posts about installing `xgboost` for Python on Windows 10, but none of them mentioned the issue I was having. In addition, all the posts seem to be about installing `xgboost` without GPU support.

I also found the [official installation guide](http://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build.html#building-on-windows) to be quite difficult to follow, as it omits certain directory changes and has some different options that disrupt the flow of commands. Below are the steps I used to install `xgboost` with GPU support on Windows 10 with Python 3.6.4:

#### Necessary software

The first step is to install the following software that will be required for this installation:

- [CMake](https://cmake.org/download/), adding CMake to your system `PATH`
- Visual Studio 2015 with Update 3 and Visual C++
- [Git for Windows](https://gitforwindows.org/), making sure to add it to the `PATH` variable
- [CUDA](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-90-download-archive?target_os=Windows&target_arch=x86_64&target_version=10&target_type=exenetwork)  Note: the version must be at least 8.0. I used 9.0 because of compatibility issues with the newer versions and Tensorflow

Ensure the following packages are installed:

```
conda install -y numpy scipy pandas matplotlib nose scikit-learn graphviz python-graphviz
```

#### Step 1: Cloning the repo

Run the following in the VS2015 x64 Native Tools Command Prompt that comes installed with VS2015 in administrator mode, in the folder you want the `xgboost` folder to be located in:

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost
cd xgboost
git submodule init
git submodule update
```

#### Step 2: Making the .sln file with CMake

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake .. -G "Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64" -DUSE_CUDA=ON
cmake --build . --target xgboost --config Release
```

#### Step 3: Installing the Python Package

If the above complete without any errors, run the following:

```
cd ../python-package
python setup.py install
```

#### Error:

At this point, I get the following error and the installation fails:

```
error: can't copy 'xgboost\lib': doesn't exist or not a regular file
```

See my answer below for my solution, and please post another answer if you find a better way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit `xgboost/python-package/setup.py` and change line 38 to the following ([source](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/1846#issuecomment-269295710)) :

```
include_package_data=False
```

Now it should install without any problems. To see that it's all working fine, just run the following command, and if it runs without errors it's good to go:

```
python -c "import xgboost"
```

You can run additional tests after installation using the `nose` package with the following command executed from the root `xgboost/` directory:

```
nosetests tests/python
```

To further confirm that it installed with GPU support, you can use the [benchmarking scripts](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gpu/#benchmarks) that come included with the installation:

gpu_hist algorithm:

```
python tests/benchmark/benchmark_tree.py
```

Output:

```
Train Time: 46.25219774246216 seconds
```

hist algorithm without GPU:

```
python tests/benchmark/benchmark_tree.py --tree_method hist
```

Output:

```
Train Time: 84.04853415489197 seconds
```