# How to Compile XGBoost using MinGW

Tags: python-3.x, xgboost, ming

I am following the instructions given [here](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build.html) and [here](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build.html#mingw-python) to get XGBoost for Python running on my Windows 10. I have installed [Git for Windows](https://git-for-windows.github.io/), but I get the error below when I try the next steps:

```
$ cp make/mingw64.mk config.mk; make -j4
cp: cannot stat 'make/mingw64.mk': No such file or directory
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

Is there any simpler approach to get XGBoost for Python running on
Windows?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33749735/how-to-install-xgboost-package-in-python-windows-platform)? Do you need GPU support? I've also asked and answered my own question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50557115/9374673) for the GPU version in case you run into an installation error while trying to install it with GPU support using Visual Studio to compile it.

Comment: Thanks, @MihaiChelaru. Let me explore and try your approach. I will return soon.

Comment: Hi, MihaiChelaru. After following your answer, I am getting this error at Step 3. Create Visual Studio Project. Any thoughts? Thanks in advance. `User@pc MINGW64 ~/xgboost_dir/build (master)
$ cmake .. -G"Visual Studio 12 2013 Win64"
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (project):
  Failed to run MSBuild command:

    MSBuild.exe

  to get the value of VCTargetsPath:

    The system cannot find the file specified
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/User/xgboost_dir/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".`

Comment: I believe you're following an answer posted by a different user. My answer uses VS 2015. Did you do the `git submodule init` step from [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33749735/how-to-install-xgboost-package-in-python-windows-platform?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment87767013_34958723) under the post whose instructions you're following?

Comment: I found your answer. You are right - I was following the wrong answer. I will update you soon.

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution to your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried using mingw for this installation as per the [official guide](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build.html#mingw-python) as well as the steps detailed [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/jfp/entry/Installing_XGBoost_For_Anaconda_on_Windows). but unfortunately I could make neither work even after many hours of efforts on my windows 10 64 bit machine. I kept encountering some error or the other

Finally, what worked for me is to install it to anaconda's [py-xgboost package](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/py-xgboost). This worked readily for me